# validar valor nulo cuando 0 es correcto

Tags: mysql

Necesito validar un resultado nulo , y me retorna "0" , cuando "0" es un valor de retorno en mi DB correcto , y deberia retornar NULL

Si doy valor por ejemplo : $variable="111542" , retorna "0" valor correcto Pero si doy valor : $variable="asd45sd8asd" ( valor ilogico ), retorna "0" valor incorrecto

DB:
Col:version ( int ) solo valores del 0 al 9
Col:indice ( int )solo valores del 1000 al 99999 
ejemplo DB:

```
primaria=1000, version=0,indice=10059;
primaria=1001, version=1,indice=10059;
```

mi consulta

```
$conexion = @new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);
if ($conexion->connect_error) {   
die('Error de conexion: ' . $conexion->connect_error);}
$sql="SELECT COALESCE(MAX(version), 'example@google.com') as version from midatabase WHERE indice='$variable' ";
$result2 = $conexion->query($sql);
while ($row = $result2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$mivariable=$row['version']; }
echo $mivariable;
$conexion->close();
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner algún registro de ejemplo para probar esa consulta? Así como el resultado esperado para esos datos de muestra

Comment: SELECT COUNT(version) AS version y me retorna 1 , di un valor ilogico ( lo busque por phpmyadmin ( que no exista ) y sigue retornarnado un valor, cuando no existe!

Comment: Tu consulta no devuelve lo que dices que devuelve para los datos de muestra que has puesto. Por favor, revísala. Y, sobre el valor de `$variable`, deberías filtrarla en PHP antes de enviarla al servidor MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lo que indicas, te sugiero comprobar el valor de `$variable` antes de enviar ese query al servidor MySQL. Algo así:

```
$conexion = @new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);
if ($conexion->connect_error){   
    die('Error de conexion: ' . $conexion->connect_error);
}
$mivariable=null;
if($variable>0){
    $sql="
        SELECT COALESCE(MAX(version), 'example@google.com')
            as version
            from midatabase
            WHERE indice='$variable' 
    ";
    $result2 = $conexion->query($sql);
    while ($row = $result2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $mivariable=$row['version'];
    }
}
echo $mivariable;
$conexion->close();
```

Comment: Tenes razon , probe dando valores "logicos" y retorna valores correctos , estaba probando consultas asignando una string asi me aseguraba que no exista , lo cual me retornaba una valor incorrecto , ahora voy a validar la $variable antes de la consulta asi se que el valor ingresado sea logico! y con COUNT si retorna valor es que existe tambien tenias razon!